# React-Native Firebase sdk

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I have been 2 days trying to get react native and firebase to work. I installed firebase following the instructions on expo docs. I get errors telling me the functions from firebase are undefined in expo go, but in the web browser it works fine. Here is code:

````
import { View, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Stack, useRouter } from 'expo-router';

import { COLORS, icons, SIZES } from '../constants';

// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithRedirect, getRedirectResult } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  //my data
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();

function Login() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [loggedIn, setloggedIn] = useState(false);
    var user = false;

    async function handleLogin() {
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getRedirectResult(auth)
            .then((result) => {
                // The signed-in user info.
                user = result.user;
                console.log(user);
                if (result.user) setloggedIn(true);
            }).catch((error) => {
                // Handle Errors here.
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
            });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (loggedIn) router.push('main');
    }, [loggedIn]);
    

    return (
        
        <View style={{ flex: 1,padding: SIZES.medium }} >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLogin}>
            <Text>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

export default Login;```

I have tried a ton of stuff and it just doesnt work. Could it be that I need to build the app completely? Here is expo docs: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/
````

Answer (score 0):

Update: You need to use react-native-firebase, the other package will only work with react native web. To be able to use react-native-firebase with expo make development builds. For any questions feel free to ask here